next-auth v4 forwards to /store
I am not setting a callbackURL and I do have NEXT_AUTH_URL defined but it does not include the substring store and neither do I have any code pointing to /store in my app and neither do I have a store page.
I am able to successfully authenticate with Google, Discord, and other OAuth2 providers, but after next-auth succesfull sign in or sign out, I can see next-auth is attaching a forward header to /store on my Chrome DevTools network tab. This results in a 404 for the user and I don't see any documentation on this elsewhere. Any ideas?

related commit: https://github.com/Vandivier/ladderly-3/pull/303/commits/8cd71ab8d5cb7427f2b276118a5f5577befbb0de

I don't have a root cause fix here, but a workaround is to disable redirection and specify our own callbackUrl manually in the client, which is getting respected:
  const handleSignIn = async () => {
    await signIn(undefined, { callbackUrl: '/' });
  };

  const handleSignOut = async () => {
    const data = await signOut({ redirect: false, callbackUrl: "/" });
    setSession(null);
    router.push(data.url);
  };

